# Linked List Operations in C Read Proof

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write up all the linked list basic operations (push, pop, add_at_end, pop_from_end, add_at_index, pop_from_index). This is not a school assignment, even though it may look like one. I have written the code. I have tested it myself quite a bit, although I am no C guru. I would like it if you could tell me if there are any suggestions / corrections you have for the code in terms of efficiency, memory handling, readability, clarity etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head);
void push(node_t ** head, int data);
int pop(node_t ** head);
int add_at_end(node_t ** head, int data);
int remove_last(node_t * head);
int add_at_index(node_t ** head, int n, int data);
int remove_by_index(node_t ** head, int n);


int main()
{
    node_t * head = NULL;

    head = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (head == NULL) {
      return 1;
    }
    head->data = 1;
    head->next = NULL;
    print_list(head);
    return 0;
}

void push(node_t ** head, int data) {
    node_t * new_node;
    new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = *head;
    *head = new_node;
}

void print_list(node_t * head) {
    node_t * current = head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
}

int add_at_end(node_t ** head, int data) {
    node_t * new_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next=NULL;
    if(*head==NULL){
        *head = new_node;
        return 1;
    }
    node_t * current = *head;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = new_node;
    return 1;
}

int add_at_index(node_t ** head, int n, int data) {
    node_t * current = *head;
    node_t * temp_node = NULL;
    if(n == 0 || *head==NULL){
        push(head, data);
        return 1;
    }
    while(n>1 && current->next!=NULL){
        current = current->next;
        n--;
    }
    if(n>1){
        return -1;
    }

    temp_node = malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    temp_node->data = data;
    temp_node->next = current->next;
    current->next = temp_node;
    return 1;
}

int remove_by_index(node_t ** head, int n) {
    node_t * current = *head;
    node_t * curr_head = NULL;
    if(n == 0||*head==NULL){
        pop(head);
        return 1;
    }
    while(n>0 && current->next!=NULL){
        curr_head = current;
        current = current->next;
        n--;
    }
    if(n>0){
        return -1;
    }
    curr_head->next = current->next;
    free(current);
    return 1;
}


int pop(node_t ** head) {
    int retval = -1;
    if (*head == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }
    if ((*head)->next == NULL) {
        printf("here");
        retval = (*head)->data;
        free(*head);
        *head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }
    node_t * next_node = NULL;
    next_node = (*head)->next;
    retval = (*head)->data;
    free(*head);
    *head = next_node;
    return retval;
}

int remove_last(node_t * head) {
    int retval = 0;
    if (head->next == NULL) {
        head->data;
        free(head);
        head = NULL;
        return retval;
    }

    node_t * current = head;

    while (current->next->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    retval = current->next->data;
    free(current->next);
    current->next = NULL;
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

*1.* You can add some comments !

*2.* In my opinion you should create another `struct` that will be named like `linked_list_t` which will have two pointers, `node_t * start` ,`node_t* end`.In terms of efficiency, by doing this, you don't have to iterate all the list on `add_at_end` to add a single node (this is a common practice when you create a `linked_list`)

*3.* When you malloc you can check the `returned pointer` and if it is `NULL` you should `perror()` the message.

*4.* The code

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * next;
} node_t;

void print_list(node_t * head);
void push(node_t ** head, int data);
int pop(node_t ** head);
int add_at_end(node_t ** head, int data);
int remove_last(node_t * head);
int add_at_index(node_t ** head, int n, int data);
int remove_by_index(node_t ** head, int n);
```

should be put on a `header file` as it just contains `declarations`

*5.* Use [Sentinel Nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) in order not to iterate on `int remove_last(node_t *)`

Comment: This is great, but, if you are going to re-work the code, consider adding 'sentinel' nodes in to your new `linked_list` struct. [Sentinel nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_node) make a lot of the error and bounds-checking code obsolete, and in the long run simplify the code at the small expense of additional memory used. Note that the advice about the struct is not going to help prevent the full-scan of the `remove_last` because you need a pointer to the second-to-last as well. Consider a double-link for that.

Comment: @rolfl Yes you are right! I will add your proposal to my answer!

Comment: Why put the declarations in a header file? Since this file has a `main()` it's not going to be used by other modules, so there's no need to publish an API. Since the module seems self-contained, they could all be made `static`, though.

Comment: @Gauthier It is a good practice, nothing more.

Comment: @ThemisBeris: it depends on the intended visibility of the function. If a function is meant to be used by other modules: declare it in a separate header file (and include the header file in the defining c file), just as you wrote. If a function is *not* meant to be used by other modules: make the function (and its prototype if you have it) `static`. You're right that this needs addressing in OP's code.